# Filter JSON based of path and regex

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I want to be able to have a user be able to specify a path and a valid regex and return a filtered JSON based on that.

I think I almost have my solution except that I don't know how to dynamically get the results of a path. Here's my code:

```
function getResult(jsonObject, pathText, regexToCheck) {
    var pathArr = pathText.split(".")
    var jsonPath = ''
    console.log('start...')
    for(var key in pathArr){
        var addPath = "['"+ pathArr[key] +"']"
        jsonPath += addPath
    }
    result = jsonObject[jsonPath]
    return result.match(new RegExp(regexToCheck, 'g'), match)
}

function filterBy (json, path, regexToCheck){
    var parseJSON = json
    var filterResult = [];
    for(var obj in parseJSON){
        var result = getResult(parseJSON[obj], path, regexToCheck)
        console.log(result)
        if (result == true){
            filteredResult.push(parseJSON[obj])
        }
    }
    return filterResult
}

filterBy(json, path, regexToCheck)
```

What I would like like previously mentioned is have a user specify a path and regex like `var path = 'configurationId.id'` and `var regexToCheck = /^[4]/` and given the test data below

```
var json = [{
    "configurationId": {
      "id": "7000",
      "displayName": "7000",
      "uri": "/configuration/users/7000"
    },
    "licenseProperties": {
      "hasClientAccess": true
    },
    "roles": {
      "actualValue": [{
          "id": "Agent",
          "displayName": "Agent",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
        },
        {
          "id": "SMS",
          "displayName": "SMS",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "configurationId": {
      "id": "7001",
      "displayName": "7001",
      "uri": "/configuration/users/7001"
    },
    "licenseProperties": {
      "hasClientAccess": true
    },
    "roles": {
      "actualValue": [{
          "id": "Agent",
          "displayName": "Agent",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
        },
        {
          "id": "SMS",
          "displayName": "SMS",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "configurationId": {
      "id": "7002",
      "displayName": "7002",
      "uri": "/configuration/users/7002"
    },
    "licenseProperties": {
      "hasClientAccess": true
    },
    "roles": {
      "actualValue": [{
          "id": "Agent",
          "displayName": "Agent",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
        },
        {
          "id": "SMS",
          "displayName": "SMS",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "configurationId": {
      "id": "4003",
      "displayName": "4003",
      "uri": "/configuration/users/4003"
    },
    "licenseProperties": {
      "hasClientAccess": true
    },
    "roles": {
      "actualValue": [{
          "id": "Agent",
          "displayName": "Agent",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
        },
        {
          "id": "SMS",
          "displayName": "SMS",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
        }
      ]
    }
  }];
```

Have the result return back,

```
{
    "configurationId": {
      "id": "4003",
      "displayName": "4003",
      "uri": "/configuration/users/4003"
    },
    "licenseProperties": {
      "hasClientAccess": true
    },
    "roles": {
      "actualValue": [{
          "id": "Agent",
          "displayName": "Agent",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/Agent"
        },
        {
          "id": "SMS",
          "displayName": "SMS",
          "uri": "/configuration/roles/SMS"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Since my regex just checks to see if the id starts with 4. It's also important to note that this has to work with nested JSONs hence the path specification. So, to re-iterate the place my code fails is essentially here: `result = jsonObject[jsonPath]`

Comment: try GSON https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @yoga that's for Java not Javascript. Also if possible id like to keep it pure JS without the need of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it just ended up being a loop where you go down the path based of the an array you provided previously. Here's my complete solution and I fixed a bug for whenever you want to go through an array inside an object

```
export function filterBy (json, path, regexToCheck) {
  var parseJSON = json
  var filteredResult = []
  for (var obj in parseJSON) {
    var result = getResult(parseJSON[obj], path, regexToCheck)
    if (result == true) {
      filteredResult.push(parseJSON[obj])
    }
  }
  return filteredResult
}

function getResult (jsonObject, pathText, regexToCheck) {
  var pathArr = pathText.split('.')
  var testObj
  var testResult
  var foundmatch = false
  for (var item in pathArr) {
    // Handles Arrays
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(jsonObject) == '[object Array]') {
      jsonObject.forEach(function (obj) {
        testObj = ''
        testResult = ''
        testObj = obj[pathArr[item]]
        testResult = testObj.match(new RegExp(regexToCheck, 'g'))
        if (testResult != null) foundmatch = true
      })
    } else {
      testResult = ''
      jsonObject = jsonObject[pathArr[item]]
    }
  }

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(jsonObject) != '[object Array]') {
    jsonObject = jsonObject.match(new RegExp(regexToCheck, 'g'))
    if (jsonObject != null) foundmatch = true
  }

  return foundmatch
}
```